"Shuttlecock" antenna
During the 1960s, it was common to see a radio aerial which looked rather like a shuttlecock clamped to the gutters of older houses. I estimate that the downward-pointing wires were of the order of 6" long, and there was no whip projecting from the centre.

This predated significant uptake of VHF, and in fact domestic wireless receivers still made heavy use of longwave. The residents appeared in many cases to be elderly and respectable, and the prevalence of this design argues against their being Russian spies with concealed microwave transmitters.
I don't know the feed arrangement, but speculate that it was to the wires with the gutter clamp insulated. The wires might have been intended for top-loading, or "since they point downwards they will prevent your house being struck by lightning" (please note the quotes: I intend that to be read as an advertising claim).
For what it's worth, the area in which I saw these was the Northern Welsh Marches in the UK. I mention this in case they were the brainwave of some local wholesaler, or were provided with sets rented from a chain of shops in the area.
Can anybody identify the antenna type conclusively, and comment on its efficacy?

Hi Mark, do you have any notion of what they were used for: television, broadcast radio, shortwave listening, etc? Do you happen to know of any actual pictures of an example installation?

@webmarc There were so many around that they can only have been used for- as I suggested- broadcast radio (LW or MW): too many for shortwave and TV ownership was by no means universal. I've been looking for photos but have come up with nothing: they were common (in my neck of the woods) but presumably were scrapped when the gutters were changed.

Where was this? Such devices certainly were not common by the early 1970's near Philadelphia where I grew up.

@JonCuster Where's Philadelphia? :-) I specifically said North Welsh Marches in the UK... I don't think anybody wants me to provide the list of counties, walled cities and so on that that encompasses :-)

Totally reminds me of a discone.

@MichaelHarvey But as I said in my comment to your answer that was deleted, there were only the down-pointing elements and the wire length was (very) short relative to the wavelength (unless the owners really were Russian spies with a microwave Tx). Also I think that a discone would be invariably fed by coax, which was relatively rare (in consumer applications) in the 1960s... I strongly suspect that whatever it was that I remember was already fairly old and was used in conjunction with a conventional earth spike.

@MarkMorganLloyd - sigh, F- for my reading comprehension. I do remember some fairly unusual UHF TV antennas which were 400MHz and up.

Are you certain they were antennae, and not some kind of device designed to flummox squirrels or birds or something?

@user1172763 Yes. Leaving aside the fact that I was told (at my first school) that the funny thing clipped to the headmaster's gutter was for his wireless set, back in those days there were fewer people around who believed that fastening something 6" long to the roof would magically dispel vermin.

@JonCuster F- for my sanity after this many years, but my memory's fairly good :-) The element size would be about right for that sort of frequency, but I don't believe there was an upward-pointing whip or horizontal discone element(s). Also 400MHz would have been well above the VHF (45-215MHz) used for the UK's 405-line B&W TV, and those who had one normally had their (large X- or H-style) TV aerial mounted high on the chimney. UHF (with much smaller Yagis) was gradually introduced only after about 1965.

@MarkMorganLloyd what brand of wireless set were they used with, or were popular back in the day? I'd start there as they may have instructions for hooking up to these alleged aerials.

@webmarc The aerial would be more likely provided- and often fitted by- the shop that sold the set, or a householder that thought he knew what he was doing would buy one by mail order. The fact that nobody else recalls this sort of thing suggests that the first of those is more likely, i.e. (as suggested in my OP) they were the brainchild of a local wholesaler: whether there was some attempt at theory behind them ("top-loading") or they were just a gimmick ("anti-lightning") is thus lost in the mists of time.

OK, well if you're happy to give up then so am I :-)

@webmarc Who said I was giving up? :-) But I think that if I were to tackle this I'd need to get in touch with local-history societies in the area: something which I actually have reason to want to do at some point, but probably not within the attention span of most readers :-)

I went through a few 1960's era QSTs online, but didn't see anything like the picture. The UK must have a similar magazine, perhaps those would be a possibility. Or an old ARRL Antenna handbook?

@JonCuster I'd put my money on 1940/50s "Practical Wireless" or similar. However local history groups might be more useful, or possibly tracking down (the successors of) local wireless shops: fuzzy memory suggests a number called (I think) D.E.Roberts which I believe is unconnected with Roberts who make DAB receivers.

I zipped through some 1950's Practical Wireless and Practical Television magazines over at https://www.worldradiohistory.com/Practical_Television_Magazine.htm but saw nothing.

I'd say a discone as well. The OP says, "This predated significant uptake of VHF", but UHF TV has been around since the 1950s, and so did VHF FM radio in the UK. So if it wasn't an antenna, maybe it was a lighting "diffuser".  Even today, my insurance agent says I can get a discount on my home insurance if I install a lightning rods.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arfon_transmitting_station and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moel-y-Parc_transmitting_station have details on Welsh TV frequencies through the years. BBC2 Wales at Moel-y-Parc was at 663.25MHz starting in July 1969 - perhaps the antenna in question was built for the new station at a very different frequency than the previous (179.75 and 204.75MHz)? Afton added new channels only in 1975 it seems, at 631.25, 655.25, and 711.25MHz.

@JonCuster I am familiar with those transmitters. As I said, these were early-60s and normally looked as though they had been in service much longer. They were absolutely NOT TV aerials.

@MarkMorganLloyd - Roger that. I’m out of ideas, sadly. Although none seem to have been very good…

@LouisSeaman UHF was introduced to the more "important" parts of the UK- i.e. the Home Counties- in the mid-late '60s. These aerials predate that. For the moment I think I'll assume it was a gimmick: grossly inadequate top-loading (for LW/MW) and a pretense at "anti-lightning" since the pointy bits were oriented downwards. I'll try to follow up with local history groups etc.
